# How to get null value in azure expression

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I created a derived column in ADF using dynamic content as
`iif(instr({userID},'_') > 0,toInteger(split({userID},'_')[2]),0)` but I am unable to set it to default null instead of 0.
Above I am splitting all the digits after '_' and setting them as my output. But if there is no underscore then it should return a null.

Example 1:
Input 2jifh-ndifh3-idhf37-2323sd_445589
Output 445589

Example 2:
Input mkla4-5gj79a-df32ws-389shj-ks78ol
Output Null

Comment: Have you tried "null()" or "toString(null())"?

Comment: In this case, you should use toInteger(null())

Comment: toInteger(null()) Worked Thanks @MarkKromerMSFT

Answer (score 0):

### --Update

Adding the answer by @MarkKromerMSFT for reference. Thanks Mark!

`toInteger(null())` will work.

---

If you go through the official MS doc here for [iif](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#iif)

> Based on a condition applies one value or the other. **If other is
> unspecified it is considered NULL**. Both the values must be
> compatible(numeric, string...).

So you can try just,

```
iif(instr({userID},'_') > 0,toInteger(split({userID},'_')[2]))
```

Comment: Expression type could not be evaluated, correct the ex.
This is the error is it showing.